# How to connect to SQL Server using org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mongo-jdbc-driver

There is an application that I only can Update the configuration of this app ( not the code)

This system is using org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver to connect to database scrip in a file like the script below

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB3C9CFAE07A
SET DATABASE GC 0
...

CREATE MEMORY TABLE Table1(Field1 BIGINT,Field2 BIGINT,Field3 BIGINT,Field4 VARCHAR(255),Field5 VARCHAR(48))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE Table2(Field1 BIGINT,Field2 BIGINT,Field3 BIGINT,Field4 VARCHAR(255),Field5 VARCHAR(48))
...

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1,10,100,'One','Ten')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(2,20,200,'Two','Twinty')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(3,30,300,'Three','Thirty')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(4,40,400,'Four','Foury')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(5,50,500,'Five','Fifty')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES(6,60,600,'Six','Sixty')
```

I took this script, modified it a little and put it in SQL Server database.

I am trying to change the config file so it can access data in SQL Server instead of the script file

here is what the config file look like

```
<property key="jdbcDriver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<property key="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydata/data/data.script"/>
<property key="jdbcUser" value="sa"/>
<property key="jdbcPass" value=""/>
```

What shall I put in the jdbcUrl to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what a JDBC driver is for?

Comment: It reads the data in the script and process it..

Comment: hsqldb for SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh I downloaded Microsoft JDBC Driver 8.2 for SQL Server from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and put it as MS recommended in C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 8.2 for SQL Server but how can I make it accessable by other apps? and what shall I write in jdbcDriver ?